# random number list generator

Tags: python, list, random

I need to make a list of random numbers than separate each number, odd or even.

Here is my current progress.

```
import random

def main():
    for x in range(20):
        number=list(random.randint(1,101))
        for number in number:
            list=number

    for x in list:
        if (number % 2) == 0:
            print("{0} is Even number".format(num))
        else:
            print("{0} is Odd number".format(num))
```

Comment: Are you aware that in Python **indentation** really matters?

Comment: Please edit and  indent your code properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think too much terms like number in number will make you confused, so I modified your code like this, I think this will help you to understand comprehensively.

```
import random
def main():
    ls = []   #define a space list
    ls_e = [] #even number
    ls_o = [] #odd number
    for x in range(20): #for loop 0-20
        number=random.randint(1,101)  #create random number between 1-101
        ls.append(number) #put number into ls
    print(ls)
    for x in range(len(ls)):  #for numbers in ls
        if (ls[x] % 2) == 0:  #check logic
            print("{0} is Even number".format(ls[x]))
            ls_e.append(ls[x]) #put into even list
        else:
            print("{0} is Odd number".format(ls[x]))
            ls_o.append(ls[x]) #put into odd list
main()
```

Comment: Why use `range(len(ls))` when the index `x` itself is not required? A for each style loop would be much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
import random

L_odd = []
L_even = []
for x in range(20):
    number = random.randint(1, 101)
    if number % 2 == 0:
        L_even.append(number)
    else:
        L_odd.append(number)
```

In this code, `append` is a method to append element to the list (for example, `L_even.append(number)` means to append number to the list `L_even`)

As the comments from @Harshal Parekh and @PM 77-1, you need to know the importance of indent of Python, and I think you need to study python basic.

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension to keep it simple. Hope this helps!

```
from random import randint

rand_nums = [randint(0, 101) for i in range(20)]
rand_odds = [i for i in rand_nums if i % 2 == 1]
rand_evens = [i for i in rand_nums if i % 2 == 0]

print(rand_nums)
print(rand_evens)
print(rand_odds)
```